# algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

help me solve this problem:

A 63 liter mixture contains milk and water in a ratio of 4:5. then x liters of milk and y liters of water are added to the mixture, resulting in a milk to water ratio of 7:5. finally , 60 liters of the mixture are drained and  replaced with 60 liters of water, resulting in a milk to water ratio of 7:8. what is the value of x+y ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $4p+5p=63\implies p=7$, so initially milk is $28$ liters and water is $35$ liters.

Comment: You should use a variable other than $x$ to avoid confusion with the $x, y$ variables given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+y$.

The final volume is $63+z.$

Consider the volume of water before and after the last step.

$$\frac 5{12}(3+z)+60=\frac 8{15}(63+z)\\
\color{red}{z=x+y=237}$$